# PHP Cpanel FreeTDS MSSQL connection

Tags: php, sql-server, cpanel, freetds

I've had a nicely working mssql connection, but something happened and I don't know what.
I installed FreeTds on Cpanel and made a PHP site that connects to a mssql server.
It was fully functional.
Then a few days later it ran into an error. A simple can`t connect to database error.
The interesting thing is that the same connection is working when I'm using the root ssh access and run with php console.
I've tried using CHMOD to give access to all users in the folder of freetds.
The phpinfo shows that the mssql driver is installed and running with freetds.
So the error only comes when Apache run the PHP script.

Any suggestions ? Thanks!